# PhantomJS driver not working for Angular 2 application - Selenium Automation

Tags: angular, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, angular2-template

I am trying to use phantomJS driver for headless browser selenium UI automations but the website is not loading.The application is created in angular 2.

Using below code -

```
driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("mysite");
Screenshot sh = driver.GetScreenshot();
sh.SaveAsFile(@"C:\Temp.jpg", ImageFormat.Png);
```

The screenshot is showing blank white screen.

How to fix this issue? Can someone please help

Answer (score 1):

Just check whether your URL works with IE11. If not, then comment out the following IE-section in **polyfill.ts**:

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
 import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
 import 'core-js/es6/object';
 import 'core-js/es6/function';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
 import 'core-js/es6/number';
 import 'core-js/es6/math';
 import 'core-js/es6/string';
 import 'core-js/es6/date';
 import 'core-js/es6/array';
 import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
 import 'core-js/es6/map';
 import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
 import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

This IE-fix will also fix your bug with PhantomJS.